# VSCode Cannot Go To Test

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpunit

In VSCode when I right click on a test there's an option to "Go to test" or use Alt + Enter to go to the test.

This doesn't seem to work.

The error I get back is

> "The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to
> resolve Resource c%5Cwork%5Cproject%5Ctests%5CJamesTest.php "

I'm guessing the error might be something to do with the slashes being changed to "%5C" but I can't find a setting which changes this anywhere.

I've put up with this for around a year now and I thought I would finally try to resolve the issue.

I believe the extension I have for phpunit tests is "PHP BY DEVSENSE"

Running Windows 10. Php 8.1. This isn't specific to any project or test, it affects them all and also is affected by projects running php 7.1.

Comment: So it's a specific plugin you're having issues with? Have you tried their support forum? https://community.devsense.com/